# No module named 'django' | Django installed | Python 3 | No virtual env

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django Models in another python script `script.py`.

This is my script

```
from os import environ
environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import sys

sys.path.append("C:/.../djangoproject/djangoproject")
from settings import *

sys.path.append("C:/.../djangoproject/myapp")

from models import video

vid = video(video_title='a title')
vid.save()
```

This is my folder structure:

```
djangoproject
_script.py
_djangoproject:
__settings.py
__ ...
_myapp
__models.py
__ ...
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\djangoproject\script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models import video
  File "C:\...\djangoproject/myapp\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Django is installed
I only have python 3
I am not using a virtual env

Is there a fix to this problem? Thank you

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install django, and show us the exact command you used to run your app.

Comment: @JohnGordon the command I used to install django is `pip install django` . I am fairly new to django so I don't know what you mean by "the command I used to run my app". Please note the file `script.py` is independant from the django project.

Comment: Above in the question, you posted "This is the error", followed by the error traceback message.  Where did that error come from?  Presumably it was the result of you running some command.  What was the command?

Comment: @JohnGordon the error originated from me running the script in my text editor sublime text. I tried now running the command python atest.py this is the error I got:

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models import video
  File "C:\...\djangoproject/myapp\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class video(models.Model):
```

Comment: ```File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.```

Comment: It looks like `pip` installed the django package for Python 3.7, but Sublime Text is configured to use some other version of Python on your computer.